# How do permissions interact with the Modern Activities Web Part?

Tags: web-part, document-library, permissions, library, activity-feed

We have a subsite that has specialized permissions for 4 user groups (e.g. North, South, East and West regions). This subsite is using the Modern experience. All four user groups have access to the subsite, but will only have library access to their corresponding region's library. For example, The North region is only granted access to the North library.

I'm trying to figure out how these specialized permissions will interact with the **Activities web part**. Will users from the East region be able to see when something has been added/updated from the North region (since this web part is on the subsite, not in the library) or will they only see updates that were added to their library? Is there a way to edit the modern web part permissions to restrict what they can see? If not, I think I may need to remove that web part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint web parts (modern and classic) are by default security trimmed, i.e. it won't show content to a user which are not allowed through permission.